# Java invalid cursor type access

Tags: java

```
public static void insertData() {
        String insertFirstName;
        String insertLastName;
        int id;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("insert First Name: ");
        insertFirstName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("insert Last Name: ");
        insertLastName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("First name " + insertFirstName + " Last Name "
                + insertLastName);

        try {
            Statement statement = null;
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "", "");
            System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
            statement = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "Select id, FirstName, LastName FROM PhoneBook";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            rs.moveToInsertRow();
            rs.next();
            while (rs.next()) {

                rs.updateString("FirstName", insertFirstName);
                rs.updateString("LastName", insertLastName);
                rs.insertRow();
            }
            statement.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("********************ERROR*********************");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

i KEEP getting 
********************ERROR*********************
Invalid Cursor Type: 1003

and i dont understand why. i have RS.next() and then i go through the While(rs.next()). What am i doing wrong? Please help thank you

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: ********************ERROR*********************
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Cursor Type: 1003
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.moveToInsertRow(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:4306)
 at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.insertData(JavaApplication7.java:89)
 at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.main(JavaApplication7.java:31)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Please edit that into the *question*, rather than just putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc of `moveToInsertRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#moveToInsertRow%28%29) says:

> The insert row is a special row associated with an **updatable** result set

(emphasis mine)

The [javadoc of ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) says:

> A default ResultSet object is **not updatable** and has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row. It is possible to produce ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following code fragment, in which con is a valid Connection object, illustrates how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates by others, **and that is updatable**. See ResultSet fields for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a updateable ResultSet:

```
statement = con.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
);
```

See the [documentation for ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for further information.

Besides that, it looks like you might be moving a bit too far with the `rs.next()` calls after the `rs.moveToInsertRow();`. The example in the docs shows how you should do it:

```
rs.moveToInsertRow(); // moves cursor to the insert row
rs.updateString("FirstName", insertFirstName);
rs.updateString("LastName",  insertLastName);
rs.insertRow();
```